# Once in a while Spark Structured Streaming write stream is getting IllegalStateException: Race while writing batch 4

Tags: spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have multiple queries running on the same spark structured streaming session.
The queries are writing parquet records to **Google Bucket** and checkpoint to Google Bucket.

```
val query1 = df1
        .select(col("key").cast("string"),from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, Map.empty[String, String]).as("data"))
        .select("key","data.*")
        .writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", path).outputMode("append")
        .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir1)
        .partitionBy("key")/*.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))*/
        .queryName("query1").start()

val query2 = df2.select(col("key").cast("string"),from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema, Map.empty[String, String]).as("data"))
            .select("key","data.*")
            .writeStream.format("parquet").option("path", path).outputMode("append")
            .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_dir2)
            .partitionBy("key")/*.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))*/
            .queryName("query2").start()
```

**Problem:** Sometimes job fails with ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Race while writing batch 4

**Logs:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Race while writing batch 4
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ManifestFileCommitProtocol.commitJob(ManifestFileCommitProtocol.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:187)
    ... 20 more
20/07/24 19:40:15 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because there are two writers writing to the output path. The file streaming sink doesn't support multiple writers. It assumes there is only one writer writing to the path. Each query needs to use its own output directory.

Hence, in order to fix this, you can make each query use its own output directory. When reading back the data, you can load each output directory and union them.

You can also use a streaming sink that supports multiple concurrent writers, such as the [Delta Lake](https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html) library. It's also supported by Google Cloud: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/getting-started-with-new-table-formats-on-dataproc . This link has instructions about how to use Delta Lake on Google Cloud. It doesn't mention the streaming case, but what you need to do is changing `format("parquet")` to `format("delta")` in your codes.

Comment: Thnks for the answer. When you say each query needs to use its own directory, did you mean each query writing to its own folder in bucket? If that is the case, my both queries are writing to different folders in the buckets.

Comment: In your codes, two queries use the same `path` variable in the `path` option. (`.option("path", path)`)

Comment: Path shows the bucket path. It is further partitioned based on some column value and then written. Will that count on the different path or it will be the same path?

Comment: Do you mean that the path is the same, but the data in these two queries is different and you ensure they will go to different partitions (aka, different sub directories)? If so, this still means the same directory.

Comment: I am facing the same issue using Spark 2.4 on EMR 5.33; Has this been fixed in higher Spark Structured streaming versions? I am using same S3 bucket with sub folders to persist Parquet files across two instances of the application. For example, one application instance writes to s3://mybucket/processed/table1 while the other application instance writes to s3://mybucket/processed/table2. Any pointers are much appreciated, thank you!